# Multiple antenna styles on FPV without true diversity

Tags: quadcopter

I did a search and couldn't find a site that stood out as RC. I was hoping you guys would be closest. Here's my question.

I bought a set of Eachine EV100 FPV goggles. Every resource I've looked at said I should update the dipole antennas. These have antenna diversity and not true diversity. I'm new to FPV and can't say I know what that means. As best I understand it true diversity has two receivers and it switches to the antenna with the strongest signal, where as antenna diversity just uses one receiver and combines the signals somehow to improve it. I could be completely pulling that out of a hat, though. It might not be right at all.

So one youtuber upgraded his, using a clover leaf style and a patch antenna. Another youtube source I trust suggested using two clover leaf styles.

I'd like to know if you can use a clover and a patch together with just antenna diversity or if I would be better off getting the two pack of clover leafs the other guys recommended.

I know the clover leaf is for picking up signals in 360 degrees where the patch is much stronger when it's pointed directly at the source. I just don't know how this stuff works, so I don't know if it works like that with these goggles or if they actually interfere and make it worse. If it doesn't cause issues, I'd think the patch and clover leaf would be the way to go.

Thanks for any help you can provide, even if it's telling me the correct forum to post this in.

Comment: It seems too high tech for [stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) at this time and I dont see a book written any time soon. My suggestion is viewing the youtube videos theres tons of videos on youtube regarding FPV builds. But I am trying to find actual schematics for connecting up FPV Cameras.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different types of diversity.  You can find a decent description [here](https://iarjset.com/upload/2016/april-16/IARJSET%2041.pdf).  The specs for your unit don't say what your unit has, but chances are it is a simple selection combiner that is determining which antenna element has the highest signal strength and switching to it.

Whatever it is, it's not really something you have any control over, unless you are thinking of modifying the RF front end of your FPV.

What you might consider instead is replacing the stock antenna elements with a higher gain solution.  Your model's antennas screw in with a standard SMA connector, so you could take them out and maybe try something like [this](https://www.getfpv.com/index.php/lumenier-axii-long-range-5-8ghz-antenna-rhcp-2.html?ccartCamp=65956434.1&recoSrc=3m-dl-samesess-alpha-avt:8144,6m-dl-samesess-alpha-fbicp:8144,6m-dl-samesess-alpha-fbi:resultset), which also has an SMA connector.

The challenge in all of this is that none of what we are looking at is military or industrial grade, so it's hard to gauge how much of what you might see is design-related or manufacturing quality related.